# Let ps tell me program full path, but not program arguments, can it?

Tags: ps

I hope to have `ps` show me a running program/process's full path, and I tried:

```
ps -e -o pid,ruser,euser,tname,ucmd

ps -e -o pid,ruser,euser,tname,cmd
```

The do not produce desired output.

- `ucmd` shows program name only without path prefix.
- `cmd` shows full path but with redundant program arguments.

[image: ps output screen]

What I need is:

```
1086 chj      chj      tty2     /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg
2794 chj2     chj2     tty3     /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg
```

Can I?

Comment: Does `exe` do what you want?